# what is a useable base image for ansible-bender based on debian?

Tags: python, docker, ansible, debian-based, buildah

I want to build a docker image with ansible-bender which is the recommended way with ansible v2.10, ansible-container is deprecated.

So... at first i thought ok i just use the debian:buster-slim image as base from docker hub

```
---
- name: whatever
  hosts: all
  vars:
    ansible_bender:
      base_image: debian:buster-slim
  tasks:
  - name: doesn't matter
...
```

It does not matter because this image does not contain an python installation

```
21:28:33.284 buildah_builder.py ERROR  couldn't locate python interpreter, tried these paths: ('/usr/bin/python3', '/usr/local/bin/python3', '/usr/bin/python3.7', '/usr/bin/python37', '/usr/bin/python3.6', '/usr/bin/python36', '/usr/bin/python2', '/usr/local/bin/python2', '/usr/bin/python', '/usr/local/bin/python', '/usr/libexec/platform-python')
```

Ok, there's a another image, python has a repo on docker hub as well and an image based on buster slim also (python:3.8-slim-buster):

```
---
- name: whatever
  hosts: all
  vars:
    ansible_bender:
      base_image: python:3.8-slim-buster
  tasks:
  - name: some task
    raw: apt-get update
```

Wonderful i thought, now i can start building the image i want. So i switched the task

```
---
- name: whatever
  hosts: all
  vars:
    ansible_bender:
      base_image: python:3.8-slim-buster
  tasks:
  - name: install some packages
    apt: 
      name: libssl-dev ca-certificates
      update_cache: yes
```

Ok, the dokumentation on the apt module did mention it, this was kind a to expect:

```
FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Could not import python modules: apt, apt_pkg. Please install python3-apt package."}
```

But what now, the python installation in this image is not the one from the distribution so installing python3-apt will not help, thats not even importable:

```
PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages python
Python 3.8.6 (default, Nov 18 2020, 14:00:57) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import apt;
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
```

And there are no python modules: apt or apt_pkg that someone could install via e.g. pip, also i am not really interested in the python installation, i want to build a docker image. Sure i want to build it with ansible and that is written in python but... has it to be that hard!? I mean, i tried to install the distribution based python 3.7 and the python3-apt package but ansible is still looking by default at the installation at /usr/local/bin because of PATH, and ;-) dont try switching PATH while running the playbook.

Am i thinking it wrong, should i use a different base image (debian is the requirement) - anyone running in same issues, has an idea!?

And yes, i am aware of the possiblity of extending the debian:buster-slim image with the distri based python installation and the needed modules in a another way, pushing that to a registry and using this as the base image. But i am lazy, and it is a another step in a very long process involving a gitlab pipeline, a api request on rundeck, another ansible playbook in rundeck and so on...

Comment: `And there are no python modules: apt or apt_pkg`. The [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/apt_module.html#requirements) states you should install `python-apt` or `python3-apt` depending on your target python version.

Comment: It is as i wrote, python-apt and python3-apt are the debian distro based wrappers for libapt, they can be used with the distri based python installation which is not part of the slim version of the buster image and the issue with that i explained in my question!